# Unwanted bind after javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my page i have a gridview which has a checkbox column on the left side. In the header i have a checkbox that should either uncheck or check the rest of the checkboxes dependant on the header checkbox state. What is happening is that the checkboxes are changing state and then the gridview RowDataBound event is then changing them back to what they were previously. My question is, Is there anyway to prevent a databind after post back other than :

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    GridView.DataBind()
End If
```

Because i already have that in my page load event.

Comment: How do you manage the header checkbox changing state event? The best way to do this is to use javascript...Here u can find a nice example => http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-Uncheck-all-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: it is passed from vb to javascript and the state is checked there. In the past the code has worked and it works on other pages but i am not sure why is isn't on here

Comment: please share code so we can learn how you bound the data to grid...

Comment: Is the check changed event firing and causing your postback? Make sure the checkboxes in the rows are only html controls, or have autopostback = false if in asp.net.